# How to fetch all Builds of a Plan in Bamboo REST API?

Tags: rest, api, bamboo

I am trying to fetch all builds of a Bamboo plan using the rest API. My plan has more than 25 builds but its giving me only 25 builds.

**API URL**: https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECTKEY-PLANKEY.json

As per the [official documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources#BambooRESTResources-GeneralInformation)

> The number of resources in returned lists is limited to 25, unless you specify max-result.

Hence, for the workaround, I thought I can fetch build size in first api call and pass size in the second api call as `max-results` parameter. So that it will give me all builds for a plan. But first API call giving me `size` 1 whereas the same is working for fetching project size.

**API call to get the build size:**  (Not Working)
  https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECTKEY-PLANKEY.json?max-results=1

`output`: size=1, max-result=1 (Whereas plan has 33 builds)

`expected output`: size=33, max-result=1

https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECTKEY-PLANKEY.json?max-results=33

**Working API to get the Project Size:**

https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/project.json?max-results=1

`output`:size=30, max-result=1

My question here, Can we fetch all BUILDS of a PLAN? As by default it only fetches 25 builds. Or any workaround?

**Update:** I have posted same problem in Bamboo forum and they found this is an [issue in Bamboo REST API](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-17961).

Answer (score 1):

Unsure whether I am reading it right or there is a typo.

You are adding "s" in max-results at the end, as seen in your http URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vidish. I have tried all ways. Its an issue in Bamboo, Please refer [this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-17961) for more info.